Import JSON as a variable only to get its type and ensure the import gets removed when compiled
I have a JSON file that is auto-generated in my repo, a TypeScript backend project with Node as target runtime. I import the JSON file like this, just to get the type of the JSON object:
import countries from '../generated/countries.json' assert { type: 'json' }
type Countries = typeof countries

The JS variable countries is not needed at runtime at all.
Is it possible to ensure it is compiled away by the TS compiler?
The motivation is to avoid Node warnings about ESM JSON imports being an experimental feature

Typically for a "type-only" import you'd do import type ... but I don't know if that will work with the import assertion.

Can't work, would need the not given possibility to do an export type from the JSON file

You might not like this solution but you could use a .ts file instead of a .json file:
// src/json/countries-json.ts
export const CountriesJSON = [
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "code": "AF"
    },
    /// ...
]

Then, create a second file:
// src/json/countries.ts
export type Countries = typeof import('./countries-json');

Before you build your project you can create .d.ts files for the JSON type:
npx -p typescript tsc src/json/countries.ts --module esnext --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly  --outDir types

You can automate this with pre- and post- hooks in npm.
It will create a types directory with two files:
// types/countries-json.d.ts
export declare const CountriesJSON: {
    name: string;
    code: string;
}[];


// types/countries.d.ts
export type Countries = typeof import('./countries-json');

You can import the type when you need it:
import type { Countries } from "./types/countries";

Bonus: Infer the type of the array items
You could also access the type of one of the items in the JSON array using type-fest:
import type { IterableElement } from 'type-fest';
export type Country = IterableElement<typeof CountriesJSON>;

The type Country is inferred as:
type Country = {
    name: string;
    code: string;
}


Hahaha, nice! But indeed a bit overkill for my situation. Thank you! Voted up

You can also try something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-ts it will be a similar solution but with less code (just a command for the terminal). You can use the command line to transform the .json file into a .d.ts file and then import it.

I have just released dts-from-json. You can use it as npx dts-from-json <json-path-or-url>. Your question gave me the idea of releasing this, so thanks!
